# Cannot connect to database because axios is in UI javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've just deployed a weather API app to Heroku and the whole UI is working fine - the only issue that I have is that I cannot fetch data from the database. I am importing a file named, 'data.js' of dummy data to the 'index.js' file which is node.js and contains my app's server. I've realized that the issue lies in my 'UI' javascript file, 'script.js' because I use, 'localhost:3000' in my axios get call. Below is a photo of what I am describing[image]

How can I make it so that my UI javascript file can contain an axios call using localhost:3000 or process.env?

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

1) If the browser application and API are hosted by the same webserver, you can just use the absolute path of the API endpoint instead of the full URL.

2) You can inspect the hostname of the browser application (`window.location.origin`) to see if it's being hosted locally or remotely. And depending on the result, you can either set the endpoint to the localhost name or the remote hostname of the API on Heroku.

3) You could also implement specific builds for different environments to substitute the correct values (in your case, for local and production). Webpack, for instance, allows you to map environment variables to your source code, in which case you could use localhost for the development build and the remote hostname in the production build.